# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' when asp classic app use azure sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, azure

I have a problem when I tried to move old application with asp classic for Windows Azure.

I recreated new DB for Azure SQL Server and my 1st application (umbraco) really working with its.

But when I create 2 application (asp classic) and used standard connection string -  I had this error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
specified.
```

when my asp pagetried to open connection.

I checked my ODBC driver and created `System DNS` and `User DNS` and found that test connection worked! I check flag `Use 32-bit application` for application pool. I tried any ways but they didn't work!

Please, help me! I don't understand where and when I mistaken!

Comment: Could you please share a redacted version of your connection string? Azure connection strings require the proper server name and user name, that may be a little different than your "standard" string. Also, have you opened the firewall on the Azure side?

Comment: I didn't understand about firewall. What do you mean?

Comment: To help protect your data, the SQL Database firewall prevents all access to your SQL Database server until you specify which computers have permission. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx

Comment: Thank! I guess that vm and sql server azure are in one space ip?

Comment: You can link the VM to the SQL Server as linked resources. That will permit them to work together. If your VM is outside of Azure, you can pen the firewall to the external address.

Comment: Thank! I understood.  Have I link my VM as link resources to existed DB in Azure SQL instance?

Comment: I did this action bit I haden't result. I imported my database in SQL Azure database instance and I tried again - nothing! What will I do for get result - link between SQL Azure database and page with ASP classic?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I had to install 'SQL Native Driver 10.0' and changed connection string in all asp pages.  After that I set up site and application pool as 'Classic mode' in IIS, turn on 'Enable 32-Bit Applications' in true. I linked on this database for all virtual machine instances.
That's all! Particularly amusing is that you have to install sql server express c abnormal termination, to get 'SQL Native Driver 10.0'